# Does my classification model suffer from information leak?

Tags: regression, ensemble-learning, stacking

I'm trying to solve a recommendation problem (recommending items to users). I have a dataset of triplets `(user, item, reaction)`, where reaction is either 0 or 1 (negative or positive) and two recommendation models:

- popularity-based: outputs relative popularity for a given item (the higher popularity is, the better).
- item-item k-nearest-neighbors: as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Item-item_collaborative_filtering).

I now want to combine predictions from both models by logistic regression, and transition from `(user, item, reaction)`-dataset to `(knn-score, popularity score, reaction)`. Since `reaction` is binary, it seems perfectly reasonable to fit a logistic regression model on it, using `knn-score` and `popularity score` as features.

The question is: can I do that on the same training set, or do I need additional cross-validation/folding, because my case seems to fit [stacked generalization/blending](http://mlwave.com/kaggle-ensembling-guide/) approach? I.e., is there a possibility that my first-order recommenders (knn/popularity model) will leak information to the regressor?

The argument against blending, I guess, is the fact that both of my first-order models are non-parametric, i.e. cannot overfit the data in the first place. They are just deterministic transformer functions (transforming `item` categorical variable to its frequency, for example, as popularity-based model does), which completely depend on data. Does this reasoning sound correct - or do I have to partition the data into folds and train first/second order models on different ones still?

Answer (score 0):

coincidentally i was trying out a github extension to sklearn (python). So if you refer to this http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/classifier/StackingClassifier/, especially the algo specified, it clearly indicates that you CAN essentially use the same data set since the meta learner in the stacking model will use the predictions of the base learners to construct a meta model. So the question of leakages dont arise. I hope i made some sense.

Besides if the classification is binary , don't you think SVM's / RandomForests can also be considered ?

Comment: Well, that's kinda strange. Every other source I can find insists on splitting the training set into two disjoint sets for base learners/meta learners ([example](https://www.quora.com/What-is-stacking-in-machine-learning)). Do you have a particular reason to trust your source over others?

Comment: @rocknrollnerd apologies for jumping the gun on that one but all sources (including your example) clearly indicate you need the k fold cross validation only for the base learners. The meta learner will use the predictions of the base learners and the actual labels on the final training set to train the system (http://mlwave.com/kaggle-ensembling-guide/) ..but i still don't get your "leakage" concerns though ..do respond since i am upping my game in this sphere as well ..thanks !

Comment: The documentation page linked (now) says exactly that:  "Please note that this type of Stacking is prone to overfitting due to information leakage. The related StackingCVClassifier.md does not derive the predictions for the 2nd-level classifier from the same datast that was used for training the level-1 classifiers and is recommended instead."