# Information leaks related to test or validation sets

Tags: validation, hyperparameter

Lately I've been reading about (indirect) information leaks, related to validation and tests sets in the context of hyperparameter tuning.

For example, Prakhar Agarwal, in his answer [Does my classification model suffer from information leak?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236322/does-my-classification-model-suffer-from-information-leak) says, that:

> "Every time you tune a hyperparameter of your model based on the
>   model’s performance on the validation set, some information about the
>   validation data leaks into the model."

How can those "informations" about validation data "leak" in general? Does it happen in situations, when I tell myself for example: "I see that hyperparameter xy (e.g. learning rate) is doing really well on validation set, as all the combinations of hyperparamters where  *that* hyperparameter had ceratain value were doing well, let's try to fix hyperparameter xy to afformentioned value and let's tune other hyperparameters."

My thoughts were that in that case *information* that *leaked* was the knowledge about the best performing value of (in our case) learning rate.

This is just my hypothesis, please correct me if I am wrong.

Another question related is, where else in the machine learning process can direct  or indirect information leaks (or "contamination" of datasets) occur?